# How can I reduce this to a single file open?

Tags: windows, perl, file, append

Using Strawberry Perl 5.22.0 in Windows 7. Is there a more "perlish" way to write this snippet of code? I hate the duplication of file open sections, but cannot think of a way to make it only open once because of the requirement to test the creation time.

```
...
my $x;
my $fh;
my $sentinelfile = "Logging.yes"; #if this file exists then enable logging
my $logfile = "transfers.log";
my $log = 0; #default to NO logging

$log = 1 if -e $sentinelfile; #enable logging if sentinel file exists

if($log){

#logfile remains open after this so remember to close at end of program!
 if (-e $logfile) { #file exists
    open($fh, "<", $logfile); #open for read will NOT create if not exist
        chomp ($x = <$fh>); #grab first row
    close $fh;
    if (((scalar time - $x)/3600/24) > 30) { #when ~30 days since created
        rename($logfile, $logfile . time); #rename existing logfile
        open($fh, ">", $logfile); #open for write and truncate
        print $fh time,"\n"; #save create date
        print $fh "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    } else { #file is not older than 30 days
        open($fh, ">>", $logfile); #open for append
    }
 } else { #file not exist
    open($fh, ">", $logfile); #open new for write
    print $fh time,"\n"; #save create date
    print $fh "--------------------------------------------------\n";
 }

} #if $log
...
```

To recap: logfile logs stuff. First row of file contains the logfile creation date. Second row contains horizontal rule. Rest of file contains text. Around 30 days after file was created, rename file and start a new one. After the above chunk of code the logfile is open and ready for logging stuff. It gets closed at the end of the rest of the program.

Comment: Why not create a scheduled task that handles the log rotation each month?  Then this script would only need 1 open call (in append mode).

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you don't want to do the scheduled task log rotation, then I'd rewrite your code to use 2 separate subs; one to rotate the log and the other to get the ctime of the logfile.  Then you could have a simple statement like this `rotatelog($logfile) if log_ctime($logfile) > 30;`

Comment: @RonBergin How will that handle the append case properly?

Comment: @NetMage The next statement would simply be: `open( $fh, ">>", $logfile );`.  You could add a die statement to that or load the `autodie` pragma.  Those 2 statements would be the only lines needed in the OP's `if ($log) {` block.

Comment: That feels inefficient - you must open/close the file an additional time in some cases.

Comment: Can you give an example where it would need to be opened multiple times?  Since the ctime value on Windows does not change like it does on *nix systems, we could check that value instead of opening and reading the timestamp in the file (as zdim has shown).  So the file only needs to be opened/closed once.

Comment: Correction, if it needs to be rotated, then obviously it would need to be opened in write mode to add the header (which is actually no longer needed)

Comment: @RonBergin The file only need be opened once, for append.  See full example added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are other, non-cosmetic problems with your code: a) You do not ever check if your calls to `open` succeeded; b) You are creating a race condition. The file can come into existence after the `-e` check has failed. The subsequent `open $fh, '>' ...` would then clobber it; c) You don't check if your `rename` call succeeded etc.

The following would be a partial improvement on your existing code:

```
if ($log) {
    if (open $fh, '<', $logfile) { #file exists
        chomp ($x = <$fh>);
        close $fh
            or die "Failed to close '$logfile': $!";
        if (((time - $x)/3600/24) > 30) {
            my $rotated_logfile = join '.', $logfile, time;
            rename $logfile => $rotated_logfile
                or die "Failed to rename '$logfile' to '$rotated_logfile': $!";
            open $fh, '>', $logfile
                or die "Failed to create '$logfile'";
            print $fh time, "\n", '-' x 50, "\n";
        }
        else {
            open $fh, '>>', $logfile
                or die "Cannot open '$logfile' for appending: $!";
        }
    }
    else {
        open $fh, '>', $logfile
            or die "Cannot to create '$logfile': $!";
        print $fh time, "\n", '-' x 50, "\n";
    }
}
```

It would be better to abstract every bit of discrete functionality to suitably named functions.

For example, here is a completely untested re-write:

```
use autouse Carp => qw( croak );

use constant SENTINEL_FILE => 'Logging.yes';
use constant ENABLE_LOG => -e SENTINEL_FILE;

use constant HEADER_SEPARATOR => '-' x 50;
use constant SECONDS_PER_DAY => 24 * 60 * 60;
use constant ROTATE_AFTER => 30 * SECONDS_PER_DAY;

my $fh;

if (ENABLE_LOG) {
    if (my $age = read_age( $logfile )) {
        if ( is_time_to_rotate( $age ) ) {
            rotate_log( $logfile );
        }
        else {
            $fh = open_log( $logfile );
        }
    }
    unless ($fh) {
        $fh = create_log( $logfile );
    }
}

sub is_time_to_rotate {
    my $age = shift;
    return $age > ROTATE_AFTER;
}

sub rotate_log {
    my $file = shift;

    my $saved_file = join '.', $file, time;

    rename $file => $saved_file
        or croak "Failed to rename '$file' to '$saved_file': $!"

    return;
}

sub create_log {
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, '>', $file
        or croak "Failed to create '$file': $!";

    print $fh time, "\n", HEADER_SEPARATOR, "\n"
        or croak "Failed to write header to '$file': $!";

    return $fh;
}

sub open_log {
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, '>>', $file
        or croak "Failed to open '$file': $!";

    return $fh;
}

sub read_age {
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $file
        or return;

    defined (my $creation_time = <$fh>)
        or croak "Failed to read creation time from '$file': $!";

    return time - $creation_time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did say this was a "snippet" of code not a real program. I'm simply looking for a better algorithm when you get down to it. Your comments are true of course but not relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Also the file open "+>>" will open a file for both read and write/append.

Comment: @NetMage If someone asks me "how can I push my car from D.C. to LA", I will recommend they put gas in the tank and drive. That would also be "completely not answering the original question".

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read a line of a file, rename it and then work with it, you have to open it twice.

However, you can also do away with using that first line.

On Windows, according to [perlport (Files and Filesystems)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Files-and-Filesystems), the *inode change time* time-stamp (`ctime`) "may really" mark the file creation time. This is likely to be completely suitable for a log file that doesn't get manipulated and moved around. It can be obtained with the `-C` [file-test operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

```
my $days_float = -C $filename;
```

Now you can numerically test this against 30. Then there is no need to print the file's creation time to its first line (but you may as well if it is useful for viewing or other tools).

Also, there is the module [Win32API::File::Time](http://search.cpan.org/~wyant/Win32API-File-Time-0.006/lib/Win32API/File/Time.pm), with the purpose to

> provide maximal access to the file creation, modification, and access times under MSWin32

Plese do read the docs for some caveats. I haven't used it but it seems tailored for your need.

A good point is raised in a comment: apparently the OS retains the original time-stamp as the file is being renamed.  In that case, when the file's too old copy it into a new one (with the new name) and delete it, instead of using `rename`.  Then open that log file anew, so with a new time-stamp.

Here is a complete example

```
archive_log($logfile) if -f $logfile and -C $logfile > 30; 

open my $fh_log, '>>', $logfile or die "Can't open $logfile: $!";

say $fh_log "Log a line";

sub archive_log {
    my ($file) = @_;

    require POSIX; POSIX->import('strftime');
    my $ts = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S", localtime);  # 20170629_12:44:10

    require File::Copy; File::Copy->import('copy');
    my $archive = $file . "_$ts";     
    copy ($file, $archive) or die "Can't copy $file to $archive: $!";
    unlink $file           or die "Can't unlink $file: $!";
}
```

The `archive_log` archives the current log by copying it and then removes it.
So after that we can just open for append, which creates the file if not there.

The `-C` tests for file existence but since its output is used in a numerical test we need `-f` first.

Since this happens once a month I load modules at runtime, with `require` and `import`, once the log actually need be rotated. If you already use `File::Copy` then there is no need for this. As for the time-stamp, I threw in something to make this a working example.

I tested this on UNIX, by changing `-C` to `-M` and tweaking the timestamp by `touch -t -c`.

Better yet, to reduce the caller's code fully move the tests into the sub as well, for

```
my $fh_log = open_log($logfile);

say $fh_log "Log a line";

sub open_log {
    my ($file) = @_;
    if (-f $file and -C $file > 30) {
        # code from archive_log() above, to copy and unlink $file
    }
    open my $fh_log, '>>', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    return $fh_log;
}
```

---

Note. On UNIX the file's creation time is not kept anywhere. The closest notion is the `ctime` above, but this is of course different. For one thing, it changes with many operations, for instance `mv`, `ln`, `chmod`, `chown`, `chgrp` (and probably others).

Comment: I played with that and it was not consistent. I found that it retained the original creation date somehow and the new file had that date in the file system. I think it has to do with the FAT file system in Windows and how a file delete doesn't actually "delete" the file it just sets a flag in the directory structure to say the file entry can be reused. That's why file undelete utilities work. If this were a *nix system I wouldn't have to do it this way.

Comment: @Mushu That's a good point.  But -- since you are renaming this log file, why not copy it into the new one and delete the old one (instead of using `rename`)?  Then the time-stamp should be created anew.

Comment: @Mushu  I added a full working example (can't test on Windows right now but it should work).